# Troubleshooting my home mail server setup

Tags: ubuntu, postfix, courier

I've got some small domain names that I host on my home server and would like to get some basic email addresses for those domains. I set up an Ubuntu 12.04 server and followed the instructions here for setting up a mail server with Postfix and Courier:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/54960...n-email-server (top rated answer)

After doing all that, I attempted to set up my info@example.com email address in Thunderbird, but it can't find the server.

I'm able to telnet into port 25 locally (i.e. `telnet 127.0.0.1 25`) and send myself a test message manually, but I can't telnet into port 25 from another computer. My ISP has informed me that they do not block any ports.

Pingability.com returns the following information about my mail server: There was a problem while talking with the mail server. Got 'ConnectException: Connection refused'

nmap -p 25 example.com yields the following:
`PORT STATE SERVICE 25/tcp filtered smtp`

What are my next steps to troubleshoot/resolve this? I'm at a dead end.

EDIT: here is my /etc/postfix/main.cf: http://pastebin.com/82TbdyjH

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mail server is most likely only listening on `localhost` (**127.0.0.1**) port **25**. You need to get it to bind to either all your network interfaces (**0.0.0.0**) or to the actual IP address that the system is using on your LAN (possibly **192.168.x.x**) type of address.

Additionally, is this computer accessible from the internet? If so you'll need to have the mail server listening on that IP's port as well -OR- use `iptables` or your home router/switch to forward all WAN traffic coming in to port 25 to your internal IP of your mail server.

You can use `netstat` to determine what your processes are listening on which IP/port combinations like so:

```
% netstat -anpt|egrep ":25|Ac|Pro"
Active Internet connections (servers and established)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address   Foreign Address   State   PID/Program name   
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:25      0.0.0.0:*         LISTEN  13649/sendmail: acc
```

In this scenario I'm running `sendmail` and it's listening on all my network interfaces (**0.0.0.0**).

Debugging mail issues can be tricky. I've written a blog post for setting up all the various components such as `sendmail`, `spamassassin`, `dovecot` (**IMAP**), etc. It's geared towards **CentOS 5.x** but there are some tricks for debugging mail server issues in the comments at the bottom.

- http://www.lamolabs.org/blog/226/how-to-setup-a-mail-server-on-centos-5/

#### UPDATE #1

Try some of the suggestions here: http://forum.slicehost.com/index.php?p=/discussion/1651/postfix-only-listening-on-localhost/p1

Specifically make sure the following is as follows:

-Make sure this line near the top of `/etc/postfix/master.cf` is not commented out:

```
smtp      inet  n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
```

-If you want to listen on port 587 as well, also uncomment the next line:

```
submission inet n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
```

-Don't forget to reload Postfix if you make changes here:

```
$ sudo postfix reload
```

Comment: Here are a couple lines from my `/etc/postfix/main.cf`. I'm guessing I'll have to edit these, but the second line throws me off a bit:  
`mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128`  
`inet_interfaces = all`  
I'm guessing I'm going to have to change the `mynetworks` line to `192.168.something.something`, correct?

Comment: no mynetworks controls what blocks of IPs can relay mail to you, the inet_interfaces = all is what specifies what interfaces to listen on. So what does netstat show for you? Do you have something listening on port 25?

Comment: Here's my netstat:  
Active Internet connections (servers and established)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1214/exim4      
tcp6       0      0 ::1:25                  :::*                    LISTEN      1214/exim4      
  
Looks like your initial guess was correct, I'm listening on localhost only.

Comment: Yup that's the problem, see my updates to the answer.

Comment: Hm, tried all of that and no improvement. Here is my /etc/postfix/main.cf, do you see anything obvious?  

http://pastebin.com/82TbdyjH

Comment: Can you compare your master.cf file to the one in this tarball? http://www.arschkrebs.de/postfix/postfix.tar.bz2. I would suggest looking at your main.cf and comparing it to the one in there too. Also I'd skim through this debugging section from the No Starch Press Postfix book: http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:HyBJfLoJoSYJ:www.postfix-book.com/debugging.html+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us. I'll look at them as well but it's best if you learn how to do this for yourself 8-).

Comment: I am not even going to begin trying to understand what happened here, but for some reason postfix wasn't running on the system. I did `sudo apt-get install postfix` and exim4 was uninstalled automatically... and now I can hit port 25 from anywhere on the internet. >.<

Comment: That always helps 8-)